# Calabash - How to generate documentation for custom steps

Tags: ruby, documentation, calabash

I have a calabash project with various scenarios and steps:

- Given I am on the splashcreen (**step 1**)
- And I'm a cat (**step 2**)
- Then I should see a mouse (**step 3**)

Is there an easy way to automatically generate documentation for all the steps of my projects ? I know about RDOC (for ruby doc) but I'm not convinced about it.

The goal is to have something like a javadoc that anyone could check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cuke-steps](https://github.com/plaa/cuke-steps) matches your purposes. It should be helpful.

> This is a small script that reads Cucumber/Gherkin step definition files and outputs pretty-printed documentation of those steps. It is meant as a tool for developers to easily see what step definitions already exist.
>
> Currently supported output formats include HTML and Confluence wiki markup.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I found few weeks ago, but forgot to post it. It does the job quite well, but had to patch the code to regroup methods by files instead of keywords ("Then", "When"...)